# How to tell patrons to ask their waitress about the compostion of the "Traveler's Dinner" offer?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

I'm the owner of "Traveler's Coffee" Café in Russia. We make an ad for our new offer – "Traveler's Dinner” – for fixed price. The composition of the offer will change every week. We have many foreign guests and usually translate the ad in English, too.

What phrase should I use to say, that the patrons should ask the waitress to know the composition of special offer, actual this week?

Current version:
*ask the composition by the waiter*

Comment: "Ask your waiter about the specials for this week."  Do not say "ask the composition by the waiter", it is confusing.

Comment: @GEdgar - I think that’s asking a different question. One could say, “Ask your waiter about this week’s Traveler’s Dinner,” though.